# Hide Panorama album in UIIamgePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am not able to hide panorama album like WhatsApp does when images are taken from gallery.I tried everything but didn't get any solution and could not find any relevant information on google too.

Comment: Append your code please.

Comment: You can use collection view for that and add images when user selecting images from gallery.

Comment: I need to hide the panorama album while taking images from gallery